# Domain Error Issue

Tags: vector

When I compute the difference between the largest and the smallest number in an empty vector(v←⍳0) using ⌈⌿(⌈/c)- ⌊⌿(⌊/c) , it gives me a domain error. This statement works fine with normal vectors and matrices.

How do I handle the exception such that it does not give me an error when the vector is empty? It should not return anything or just return a zero.

Comment: Which APL implementation are you using?

Comment: @Orbling , I am using Dyalog APL

Comment: Dyalog has guards I believe, see the [guards section of the dynamic function reference](http://www.dyalog.com/download/dfns.pdf). `{rho}c=0` would check for empty.

Comment: Mind the associativity rule. APL functions are always right-associative, so `⌈⌿(⌈/c)-⌊⌿(⌊/c)` parses as `⌈⌿((⌈/c)-⌊⌿(⌊/c))`.

Comment: @ngn Good point, I adapted my answer to protect the evaluation order.  It did yield the correct result in that test case, but better to be safe.

Comment: @Honey, you are going in for the Dyalog APL contest right? You don't seem to be thinking the questions for yourself..

Comment: Exactly, its your 3rd question when you explicitly ask about a question from Dyalog APL 2013 Contest.

Answer (score 2):

A guard is the best way to do this:

```
{0=⍴⍵:0 ⋄ (⌈/⍵)-⌊/⍵}
```

Note that the use of two reductions, one with axis specfication, is not really needed or correct actually. That is, if you want it to work on all of the elements of a simple array of any dimension, simply ravel the argument first:

```
     {0=⍴⍵:0 ⋄ (⌈/⍵)-⌊/⍵},10 10 ⍴⍳100
99
```

Or for an array of any structure or depth, you can use "super ravel":

```
     {0=⍴⍵:0 ⋄ (⌈/⍵)-⌊/⍵}∊(1 2 3)(7 8 9 10)
9
```

Note that quadML (Migration Level) must be set to 3 to ensure that epsilon is "super ravel."

Note also the equivalence of the following when operating on a matrix:

```
     ⌈⌿⌈/10 10 ⍴⍳100
99
     ⌈/⌈/10 10 ⍴⍳100
99
     ⌈/⌈⌿10 10 ⍴⍳100
99
     ⌈⌿⌈⌿10 10 ⍴⍳100
99
```

Using reduction with axis is not needed in this case, and obscures the intent and is also potentially more expensive. Better to just ravel the whole thing.

Comment: Well, I did say initially guards were the way to go in Dyalog APL.  I added the alternative as not everyone uses Dyalog (I don't) and guards are specific to it.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, [Dyalog APL has guards](http://www.dyalog.com/download/dfns.pdf), which can be used for conditional execution, and thus you can simply check for the empty vector and give a different answer.

This can be implemented in a more traditional/pure APL method however.

**This version only works in 1-dimension**

In the APL font:

```
Z←DIFFERENCE V
⍝ Calculate difference between vectors, with empty set protection
⍝ Difference is calculated by a reduced ceiling subtracted from the reduced floor
⍝ eg. (⌈⌿(⌈V)) - (⌊⌿(⌊V))
⍝ Protection is implemented by comparison against the empty set ⍬≡V
⍝ Which yields 0 or 1, and using that result to select an answer from a tuple
⍝ If empty, then it drops the first element, yielding just a zero, otherwise both are retained
⍝ eg. <condition>↓(a b) => 0 = (a b), 1 = (b)
⍝ The final operation is first ↑, to remove the first element from the tuple.
Z←↑(⍬≡V)↓(((⌈⌿(⌈V)) - (⌊⌿(⌊V))) 0)
```

Or in brace notation, for people without the font.

```
Z{leftarrow}DIFFERENCE V
{lamp} Calculate difference between vectors, with empty set protection
{lamp} Difference is calculated by a reduced ceiling subtracted from the reduced floor
{lamp} eg. ({upstile}{slashbar}({upstile}V)) - ({downstile}{slashbar}({downstile}V))
{lamp} Protection is implemented by comparison against the empty set {zilde}{equalunderbar}V
{lamp} Which yields 0 or 1, and using that result to select an answer from a tuple
{lamp} If empty, then it drops the first element, yielding just a zero, otherwise both are retained
{lamp} eg. <condition>{downarrow}(a b) => 0 = (a b), 1 = (b)
{lamp} The final operation is first {uparrow}, to remove the first element from the tuple.
Z{leftarrow}{uparrow}({zilde}{equalunderbar}V){downarrow}((({upstile}{slashbar}({upstile}V)) - ({downstile}{slashbar}({downstile}V))) 0)
```

and an image for the sake of preservation...

[image: APL Difference Function]

**Updated. multi-dimensional**

```
Z←DIFFERENCE V
⍝ Calculate difference between vectors, with empty set protection
⍝ Initially enlist the vector to get reduce to single dimension
⍝ eg. ∊V
⍝ Difference is calculated by a reduced ceiling subtracted from the reduced floor
⍝ eg. (⌈/V) - (⌊/V)
⍝ Protection is implemented by comparison against the empty set ⍬≡V
⍝ Which yields 0 or 1, and using that result to select an answer from a tuple
⍝ If empty, then it drops the first element, yielding just a zero, otherwise both are retained
⍝ eg. <condition>↓(a b) => 0 = (a b), 1 = (b)
⍝ The final operation is first ↑, to remove the first element from the tuple.
V←∊V
Z←↑(⍬≡V)↓(((⌈/V) - (⌊/V)) 0)
```

[image: APL Difference multi-dimensional]

Comment: The solution works perfectly with empty vector and 1d vector, but fails to work with a 2d vector/matrix, how to fix it? It says Rank Error

Comment: If you want your code to be dimension-agnostic, you can use `⌈/,V` instead of `⌈⌿(⌈V)`.  Monadic `,` ravels (i.e. flattens or linearizes or converts to a vector) the content of an array of any rank.

Comment: @ngn Aye, that would be a nicer way of dealing with it.  Was trying not to move far from the OPs concept.  Though it did not occur to me either.

Comment: @Honey: Using ngn's check should work, best to unravel the vector before performing the test on empty too.

Comment: I don't think this works. The expression is still evaluated, and fails with a domain error when V is empty.

Comment: I ended up using `⌈/∊,/V` to get the ceiling, as the reduced ravel did not end up in a vector.

Comment: What does this do ⌈/∊,/V that is not accomplished by simply ⌈/,V

Comment: You definitely do NOT want to do a catenate reduction: ,/

Comment: @PaulMansour: It might be a matter of my variant of APL (NARS2000), but `⌈/,V` is dimensionless there, so had to do the catenate and enlist.

Comment: I think this is all it boils down to:
`⌈/⍬` returns `¯1.79769E308` and 
`⌊/⍬` returns `1.79769E308` (apparently the largest number which Dyalog can represent).
If you subtract the two, the result's magnitude is too big, and you get a DOMAIN ERROR.
To avoid this, you can try to limit the minimum and maximum with some sensible values for your appliction, e.g. instead of `(⌈/,V) - ⌊/,V`, you could have `(M⌊⌈/,V) - m⌈⌊/,V`, where `m` and `M` are the limits of what numbers you can realistically have in `V`.  If `M-m` isn't too wide a gap, this would work even when `V` is an empty vector.

Comment: @ngn - interesting that dyalog returns the max/min double size.  NARS2000 returns +/-inf.

Comment: Yeah, it seems in Dyalog APL they don't have a concept of `¯` (infinity) and `¯¯` (negative infinity), as suggested in http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/APLDictionary.htm .  I'm testing at http://tryapl.org

Comment: @Orbling, ah you are using NARS2000. I thought the original question was about Dyalog. That explains it. Using NARS200,  one really does not need "empty set protection" as the basic expression works fine on an empty array, producing infinity, correct?

Comment: I think you'll find the ,/ is superfluous in the expression V←∊,/V. The enlist by itself does the exact same thing. In addition, if V is not nested, but is simple, then ,V (ravel V) is the same as ∊V (enlist V).

Comment: @PaulMansour: The OP requested that it return "empty or just a zero" - this answer was mainly intended to be a more pure APL way of handling an "if ... then" than using the guards, which are frowned upon a bit by the purist vector folk.

Comment: @PaulMansour: Correct on using enlist on its own, good call.  Have amended answer.